# (MfA) - Name property on CollectionDataContractAttribute on Dictionary type is ignored

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

*Please note I am posting this QA here to help others and as a partner to [bug report 11881 on the Xamarin.Android Bugzilla area](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=11881).  As a result the type described below is for demonstration purposes only.  I have posted an initial answer, also making reference to the same bug report, but hopefully at some point this question can be 'answered' with 'this has been fixed in version x.y'.*

I have a following type shared between Mono for Android and Windows RT sources:

```
[CollectionDataContract(Name = "MyDictionary", 
    Namespace = "http://foo.bar/schema", 
    ItemName = "pair", 
    KeyName = "mykey", 
    ValueName = "myvalue")]
public class MyDictionary : Dictionary<string, string>
{

}
```

This is read from our Web API (running on Asp.Net Web API, Framework 4.5) as XML which looks like this:

```
<MyDictionary 
 xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns="http://foo.bar/schema">
  <pair>
    <mykey>message1</mykey>
    <myvalue>Hello</myvalue>
  <pair>
  <pair>
    <mykey>message2</mykey>
    <myvalue>World</myvalue>
  <pair>
</MyDictionary>
```

When using the class as described above, this XML deserializes correctly on Windows, Windows Phone and Win-RT platforms.

However, on Mono for Android builds I get

> `System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Expected element 'ArrayOfpair' in namespace 'http://foo.bar/schema', but found Element node 'MyDictionary' in namespace 'http://foo.bar/schema'`.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I hadn't done anything wrong - I wrote an NUnitLight unit test to test whether an instance of `MyDictionary` would be serialized correctly by the Mono for Android implementation of the `DataContractSerializer`:

```
public string Serialize(object o)
{
  DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(o.GetType());
  using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    ser.WriteObject(ms, o);
    return Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());
  }
}

[Test]
public void ShouldSerializeDictionaryCorrectlyAndDeserialize()
{
  MyDictionary dict = new MyDictionary();
  dict["message1"] = "hello";
  dict["message2"] = "world";
  var s = Serialize(dict);
  Assert.That(s, Is.StringStarting("<MyDictionary"));
}
```

The unit test fails, with the output string starting 'ArrayOfpair' and *not* 'MyDictionary', which would be consistent with the original behaviour where deserialization of the *correct* XML fails because it doesn't start 'ArrayOfpair'.

This is, therefore, a good candidate for a bug in the Mono for Android implementation of the `DataContractSerializer` ([I have reported the bug here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=11881)) - but until that bug is both confirmed and fixed, a workaround will be needed.  In my case I have shared codebase issues (Android, Windows and Monotouch) to contend with and so I don't want to just rewrite this type for Android.  If I come up with a decent workaround, I'll post it on this answer.

*Please note - I don't yet know if this also applies to Monotouch - we don't yet have a complete enough build of our component to run the same test, so it might do, I just don't know.*